# error: cannot find symbol method getFlutterView()

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement method channels all the documentation videos available says to write getFlutterView() but its not working anymore what am i doing wrong

**Android Native JAVA Code** :

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;


public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    private static  final  String CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {

                if(call.method.equals("helloFromNativeCode")){
                    String greetings = helloFromNativeCode();
                    result.success(greetings);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private String helloFromNativeCode(){
        return  "Hello World from Native Android Code";
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 2):

You need to override **configureFlutterEngine** and change **getFlutterView** **getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger()**. For example:

```
 public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

new MethodChannel(getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new 
MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {

            if(call.method.equals("helloFromNativeCode")){
                String greetings = helloFromNativeCode();
                result.success(greetings);
            }

        }
    });
}

private String helloFromNativeCode(){
    return  "Hello World from Native Android Code";
}
```